# Plane tangent to both paraboloids

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Can someone help me with this calculus question? It appeared on the past exams of my multivariable calculus class.

Two paraboloids, one with equation $z=-1-x^2-y^2$ and the other with equation $z=1+x^2+y^2$, has a plane tangent to both of them. Which points on the paraboloids can work as points of tangency for this plane?

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Due to symmetry we're looking exactly for all tangent planes that contain the origin. Hence, for any point $(a,b,1+a^2+b^2)^T$ we have to solve 
$$\begin{pmatrix}a\\ b\\ 1+a^2+b^2\end{pmatrix}+\lambda\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\\ 2a\end{pmatrix}+\mu\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\\ 2b\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix},$$
which yields $a^2+b^2=1$.